# Store contact in phone contact list in Android from a file

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am using this code to store a contact from a file to the phone's contact list:

```
public void addContacts(String name, String number, String type) {
    int backRefIndex = 0;       
    String data=name+"--"+number+"--"+type;
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
             .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
             .build());      
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
              ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
         .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backRefIndex)
         .withValue(Phone.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, number)
         .withValue(Phone.TYPE, type).build());
    try {
         getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

It is running without any errors. But when the added contact is viewed from phone's contact list an error message appears `"Unfortunately contacts have stopped working"`.

What's wrong in the code?

Comment: the type attribute here has values "1","2",...

Comment: post the stacktrace of the crash

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. You can see what caused it in the commented code in my method. Your error has to be similar. Your error can be caused by some missing information too.

But before trying something see what will happen if you change `"(Phone.TYPE ,type)"` with `"(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)"`. I think that's your mistake like Sumit Chawla says in his comment.

It's good practice to add checks for null values. They can throw exception.

```
public void addContacts(String name, String number, int numberType
    , String email, String organization, String street, String city
    , String region, String postcode) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,   rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, number)
            .withValue(Phone.TYPE, numberType)
          //.withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) //Use constants for type
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(Email.DATA, email)
            //If I add Email.TYPE People(Phone's contacts application) 
            //doesn't work any more.
            //The error is: "Unfortunately contacts have stopped working"
            // .withValue(Email.TYPE,Email.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
           .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
           .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
           .withValue(Organization.COMPANY, organization)
           .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
           .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
           .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
           .withValue(StructuredPostal.STREET, street)
           .withValue(StructuredPostal.CITY, city)
           .withValue(StructuredPostal.REGION, region)
           .withValue(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, postcode)
           .build());

    try {
        mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.e(TAG, "Error adding contact!", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Log attached for this issue So its a attempt.

There could be chance that your contact provider(db) is  supporting "RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE", "RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME" column to be NULL but while performing Onclick operation, Contact Detail View needs some data for that type or name should not be null, So its crashing

So open raw_contact table and find the correct default value of "ACCOUNT_TYPE" and "ACCOUNT_NAME" columns for other contact. and use same value in your builder operation.